# Is there a way to convert .py files to .obj (3D Format)? Alternatively, if there's a way to convert .py files to .exe and then from .exe file to .obj?

Tags: python, 3d, .obj

I'd be receiving data in raw/csv/.py format. Will need sources to convert it to .obj file / .exe format which will further be converted to glTF model.

Here's what I've found out so far. But this creates a file from scratch in glTF.
https://pypi.org/project/pygltflib/

Answer (score 0):

I cant say about .obj files, but there is a library 'pyinstaller' that can convert python src files to a single .exe. Type in terminal:

```
$ pip install pyinstaller
$ pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Use flag -W if you dont want the terminal running and flag -i "favicon.ico" for setting an icon.

You will be left with many folders including a dist folder, where you will find the .exe. You can then delete the remaining files and folders created by pyinstaller.

**Remember** if your .exe is using any dependency like an image then the path of the .exe should be same as the src file as pyinstaller doesnot bundle the images into the exe

Comment: Thank you for the help. But our main goal is to convert a csv file to 3D file. I already figured out a way for conversion with .py->.exe
Thanks anyway!